# Illegal Characters in SharePoint List?

Tags: special-characters

Are there any rules around what characters you are not allowed to use in a List Multi Line Column?

- Tilde (~)
- Percent (%)
- Ampersand (&)
- Asterisk (*)
- Braces ({ })
- Backslash ()
- Colon ( : )
- Angle brackets (< >)
- Question mark (?)
- Slash ( / )
- Plus sign (+)
- Pipe ( | )
- Quotation mark (“)

Comment: By use, you refer to the column name or the column content?

Comment: u are asking the characters in the column in the list or you are talking about the file name?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/905231

Answer (score 3):

The only illegal characters for any SharePoint **field name** are:

`[` and `]`

There are no restrictions for a multi-line field **value**.

You can find all the other restrictions [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/905231).